# UISearchBar inside cancel button

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I am developing an app on XCode 5 and I don't found the answer for this.

[image: my UISearchBar]

Which method is the one that controls that "X" button on the `UISearchBar`? I tried with

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

But it doesn't work

Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847745/right-align-magnifying-glass-icon-in-uisearchbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Subclass `UISearchBar`

```
@interface CustomSearchBar : UISearchBar
```

and add delegate method of `UITextField`

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
```

in that class. hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method you are looking for

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField;
```

But this is UITextFields delegate method and you need to set delegate of UISearchBar's textfield. See this

In your header (.h) file

conform to delegates. `<UISearchBarDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
          //find the UITextField view within searchBar (outlet to UISearchBar)
          //and assign self as delegate
    for (UIView *view in searchBar.subviews)
    {
            if ([view isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) 
            {
                    UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)view;
                    tf.delegate = self;
                    break;
                }
          }
 }

 - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) aSearchBar 
{
     [aSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField 
{
     [self performSelector:@selector(searchBarCancelButtonClicked:) withObject:self.searchBar afterDelay: 0.1];
    return YES;
}
```