# UISearchbar custom in iOS 6 and 7

Tags: ios, iphone, custom-controls, uisearchbar

I want my UISearchbar should look like this.

[image]

i've tried this:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:20]];

[self.seachBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.seachBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SearchIcon"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.seachBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
[self.seachBar setText:@"Search"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Please guide or any tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: do you use searchbar displaycontroller or your add your searchbar in navigationbar

Comment: Hi iDev, I use searchbar displaycontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer below link it more helpful you don't waste your valuable time

[Right align magnifying glass icon in UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847745/right-align-magnifying-glass-icon-in-uisearchbar)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
 for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [searchBar subviews])
    {
        if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])
        {

            [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

            [[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search"]];
            [[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }

    }
```

Hope, your problem solved...