# set initial position of icon in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

My question is about how to make the default appearance of UISearchBar icon to be in left position. Because now, magnifying glass is in the center.

I have tried using UITextFiled property leftView, played with property textField.leftViewMode and none of it helped me.

I know, that there are a lot of answers, but none of it helped me.

So does someone knows how it could be done.

Comment: The best I could do was to get the magnifying glass to appear in the left side while adding text or editing within the search bar, [which I used with the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847745/right-align-magnifying-glass-icon-in-uisearchbar).  It might be that Apple really doesn't want people to be able to change the initial position of the search icon?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem to change the position of this magnifying glass while adding or editing text, but i would like to change it's initial position.