# How can I make UISearchBar look this way?

Tags: ios, swift, customization, uisearchbar

I want to have a search bar like this in my app:

[While not editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK6hN.png)

[While editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHhpw.png)

As you can see, there should be magnifying glass to the right while not editing, and clear button while editing. No cancel button.

I created CustomSearchBar class by subclassing UISearchBar:

```
import UIKit

class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        customize()
    }

    private func customize() {
        setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)

        placeholder = nil
        barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        let textField = getTextField()
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
        textField.font = textField.font?.fontWithSize(18.0)

        textField.leftViewMode = .UnlessEditing
    }

}
```

and UISearchController:

```
import UIKit

class CustomSearchController: UISearchController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    lazy var _searchBar: CustomSearchBar = {
        [unowned self] in
        let result = CustomSearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)
        result.delegate = self

        return result
    }()

    override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        get {
            return _searchBar
        }
    }

}
```

This way, I got proper font size, background colors and no cancel button.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to make this magnifying glass stay to the right of text field while not editing. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847745/right-align-magnifying-glass-icon-in-uisearchbar) and it haven't worked. Another issue is, that when I make cancel button disappear using `setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)` it also makes text cursor disappear.

Is it possible, to have bigger clear and magnifying glass icons like on the mockups?

Comment: you can customize it using reactivecocoa.and it will easy to do that， i have customized a more difficute control.